# Cannot unistall app after removing or changing location of setup.msi file

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation, setup-project, uninstallation

I have created a deployment procejct which registers a COM object. The output file is a setup.msi file.

After installation I moved the file into other directory. While unistalling my product I recived

> The error the feature you are trying to use is on a network resource
>   that is unavailable.

So I must point to the directory where setup.msi is placed to continue the uninstall process. 
Is there any workaround for this issue?

I am using Custom Actions in this project.
Maybe WiX will resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

1. Instead of moving the file only copy it. This way the uninstall
   process can access the original file.
2. Select the MSI package when the uninstall process prompts for it
   (with the error message).

Using another setup authoring tools won't do anything. If the uninstall process needs to access a file which was moved, renamed or removed, it will prompt for the package to get the file.